# Semantic ui - login form fills entire page

Tags: semantic-ui

I am designing a good looking login form in my semantic ui

my form is filling the entire laptop screen. How to make it center aligned. The font size and the form size should increase based on the device size (in which i run the app)

Some one please suggest a solution.

[image]

My html code is as below.

```
<div class="ui center aligned grid">
    <div class="twelve wide column">        
      <div class="ui container">
        <h3>Log-in to your account</h3>
      </div>   
        <form class="ui form">
            <div class="ui stacked secondary segment">
                <div class="field">
                    <div class="ui left icon input">
                        <i class="user icon"></i>
                        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="User Name" ng-model="username">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    <div class="ui left icon input">
                        <i class="lock icon"></i>
                        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="password">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ui fluid large teal submit button" ng-click="login()">Login</div>
            </div>
            <div class="ui error message"></div>
        </form>
        <div class="ui message">
            New to us? <a href="http://s.codepen.io/voltron2112/debug/PqrEPM?">Register</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<style type="text/css">
/* Some basic formatting */

code {
    background-color: #E0E0E0;
    padding: 0.25em 0.3em;
    font-family: 'Lato';
    font-weight: bold;
}

.container {
    padding: 3em 0em;
}

img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
}

/* Shows content box (not negative margins) */

.grid {
    position: relative;
    padding : 3em;
}

.grid:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 1rem;
    left: 1rem;
    background-color: #F0F0F0;
    content: '';
    width: calc(100% - 2rem);
    height: calc(100% - 2rem);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px #DDDDDD inset;
}

.ui.divided.grid:before,
.celled.grid:before {
    display: none;
}

.ui.aligned .column:after {
    display: none !important;
}

.grid .column:not(.row):not(.grid):after {
    background-color: rgba(86, 61, 124, .15);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px rgba(86, 61, 124, 0.2) inset;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    min-height: 50px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .stackable.grid:before {
        width: 100%;
        left: 0em;
    }
}
</style>
```

Regards,
Sabarisri

Comment: Can you include some HTML into your question please.

Comment: @GoranMottram Hi, I have added my html code. I just proceeded to next page development, as my time limit is short. Sorry for delay. Please suggest me a solution.

Answer (score 0):

you need add  this style

```
body>.grid {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #DADADA;
}

.image {
    margin-top: -100px;
}
.column {
    max-width: 450px;
}
```